# Office Online documents error: the file is locked for shared use by another user

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, office-online-server, f5

We have the following setup: SharePoint 2019 farm with 4 servers: 2 WFE servers - load balanced by an F5 LB, 2 APP servers and a connection with a 2 server Office Online Farm, also load balanced by an F5 LB.
Both, the Web Application and the OOS URL are accessible from the internet.

The steps for reproducing the error:

- Access the Web Application from the internet
- Edit an Office document (word, excel) in the browser.
- When closing the document, the last modified date does not update, only after refresh.
- Afterwards when trying to rename the document the following error occurs: "the file is locked for shared use by another user" - which is the same user that edited the file in the first place.

On the server this does not occur and also when reproducing the above steps from inside the network.

All this points to the F5 setup as the ULS logs and OOS logs don't show anything conclusive.
Any ideas?

Comment: What session settings are you using for your SharePoint and OOS endpoints on the F5?

Comment: No session settings for Sharepoint and OOS.

Sharepoint farm point to OOS VIP without authentication

Comment: There have to be session settings, i.e. persistent/sticky, round robin, etc. You should verify that the VIPs are using persistent/sticky sessions.

Comment: looks like currently only one server is up in the oos pool, one was removed from the oos farm.

Comment: Can you temporarily bypass the F5 for all clients (point DNS at the lone OOS server) and see if the issue persists for all users?

Comment: We patched the OOS servers with the July 2020 update (kb4484451) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Whether all files have lock behavior? Can other users rename file?

1.The file may be locked when the file is not closed expectedly so that the file cache is still stored in system or browser showing the file is in use. In other words, the file lock behavior is for protecting saving conflict. In this situation, I suggest you clear browser cache and check if there’s TMP for the file.

2.Check whether there is any security software on the computer.

Here’re some references:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/313472/the-document-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-user-error-message-when

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-file-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-user-6fa93887-2c2c-45f0-abcc-31b04aed68b3

Comment: All files get locked. No users can rename them, service accounts or plain users.
Tried clearing the cache, same behavior

The weird thing is that it happens only when accessing from the internet, in the network it works fine.

We already checked the documentation you posted :), no luck.